# How do I generate spline bases from a character vector of response variables?

Tags: r, mgcv

I am working on a problem where I need to fit many additive models of the form `y ~ s(x)`, where the response `y` is constant whereas the predictor `x` varies between each model. I am using `mgcv::smoothCon()` to set up the bases, and `lm()` to fit the models. The reason why I do this, rather than calling `gam()` directly, is that I need the unpenalized fits. My problem is that `smoothCon()` requires it `object` argument to be unquoted, e.g., `s(x)`, and I wonder how I can generated such unquoted arguments from a character vector of variable names.

A minimal example can be illustrated using the `mtcars` dataset. The following snippet shows what I am able to do at the moment:

```r
library(mgcv)
# Variables for which I want to create a smooth term s(x)
responses <- c("mpg", "disp")
# At the moment, this is the only solution which I am able to make work
bs <- list(
  smoothCon(s(mpg), data = mtcars),
  smoothCon(s(disp), data = mtcars)
)
```

It would be nicer to be able to generate `bs` using some functional programming approach. I imagine something like this, where `foo()` is my missing link:

```r
lapply(paste0("s(", responses, ")"), function(x) smoothCon(foo(x), 
data = mtcars))
```

I have tried `noquote()` and `as.symbol()`, but both fail.

```r
responses <- c("mpg", "disp")
lapply(paste0("s(", responses, ")"), 
              function(x) smoothCon(noquote(x), data = mtcars))
#> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

lapply(paste0("s(", responses, ")"), 
              function(x) smoothCon(as.symbol(x), data = mtcars))
#> Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by converting to language `class`, `eval`uate and then apply the `smoothCon`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- paste0("s(", responses, ")") %>%
          map(~ rlang::parse_expr(.x) %>% 
                   eval %>%
                  smoothCon(., data = mtcars))
identical(out, bs)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try like this?

```
smoothCon(s(get("disp")), data = mtcars)
```

and, instead of `disp` you give the name of the variable you prefer. You can even put this within a loop or any other construct you prefer

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, unfortunately. I tried:
`for(r in responses){ smoothCon(s(get(r)), data = mtcars)}`